# How to fix intellijIDEA not starting problem?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13

Today when I tried to start intellij IDEA from my desktop, it did not start, just a waiting cursor occurred and no action after that. so I tried to run it form command line and ran the
idea.bat from the bin directory of Intellij installation folder: the following is the log appeared when I did this, Intellij did not open this way either.the first line of the log shows some error message:

```
    C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.1\bin>idea.bat
ERROR: The file is locked: C:\Users\iamhu\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2021.2\icons-v3.db
org.jetbrains.mvstore.MVStoreException: The file is locked: C:\Users\iamhu\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2021.2\icons-v3.db
        at org.jetbrains.mvstore.FileStore.<init>(FileStore.java:109)
        at org.jetbrains.mvstore.MVStore$Builder.createFileStore(MVStore.java:3988)
        at org.jetbrains.mvstore.MVStore$Builder.openOrNewOnIoError(MVStore.java:3952)
        at com.intellij.ui.svg.SvgCacheManager.<init>(SvgCacheManager.java:61)
        at com.intellij.util.SVGLoader$SvgCache.<clinit>(SVGLoader.java:81)
        at com.intellij.util.SVGLoader.load(SVGLoader.java:214)
        at com.intellij.util.ImageLoader.loadByDescriptorWithoutCache(ImageLoader.java:261)
        at com.intellij.util.ImageLoader.loadByDescriptor(ImageLoader.java:227)
        at com.intellij.util.ImageLoader.loadImage(ImageLoader.java:152)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader$ResolvedImageDataResolver.loadImage(IconLoader.java:1083)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader$CachedImageIcon.loadImage(IconLoader.java:962)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader$ScaledIconCache.getOrScaleIcon(IconLoader.java:1031)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader$CachedImageIcon.getRealIcon(IconLoader.java:850)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader$CachedImageIcon.getIconWidth(IconLoader.java:778)
        at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.scaleIconToSize(AppUIUtil.java:191)
        at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.loadApplicationIcon(AppUIUtil.java:187)
        at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.loadApplicationIconImage(AppUIUtil.java:166)
        at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.updateWindowIcon(AppUIUtil.java:83)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.updateFrameClassAndWindowIcon(StartupUtil.java:617)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$start$4(StartupUtil.java:173)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Exception in thread "JobScheduler FJ pool 0/3" java.lang.AssertionError: The file is locked: C:\Users\iamhu\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2021.2\icons-v3.db
        at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.DefaultLogger.error(DefaultLogger.java:54)
        at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:208)
        at com.intellij.util.SVGLoader$SvgCache.<clinit>(SVGLoader.java:84)
        at com.intellij.util.SVGLoader.load(SVGLoader.java:214)
        at com.intellij.util.ImageLoader.loadByDescriptorWithoutCache(ImageLoader.java:261)
        at com.intellij.util.ImageLoader.loadByDescriptor(ImageLoader.java:227)
        at com.intellij.util.ImageLoader.loadImage(ImageLoader.java:152)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader$ResolvedImageDataResolver.loadImage(IconLoader.java:1083)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader$CachedImageIcon.loadImage(IconLoader.java:962)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader$ScaledIconCache.getOrScaleIcon(IconLoader.java:1031)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader$CachedImageIcon.getRealIcon(IconLoader.java:850)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader$CachedImageIcon.getIconWidth(IconLoader.java:778)
        at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.scaleIconToSize(AppUIUtil.java:191)
        at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.loadApplicationIcon(AppUIUtil.java:187)
        at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.loadApplicationIconImage(AppUIUtil.java:166)
        at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.updateWindowIcon(AppUIUtil.java:83)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.updateFrameClassAndWindowIcon(StartupUtil.java:617)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$start$4(StartupUtil.java:173)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.mvstore.MVStoreException: The file is locked: C:\Users\iamhu\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2021.2\icons-v3.db
        at org.jetbrains.mvstore.FileStore.<init>(FileStore.java:109)
        at org.jetbrains.mvstore.MVStore$Builder.createFileStore(MVStore.java:3988)
        at org.jetbrains.mvstore.MVStore$Builder.openOrNewOnIoError(MVStore.java:3952)
        at com.intellij.ui.svg.SvgCacheManager.<init>(SvgCacheManager.java:61)
        at com.intellij.util.SVGLoader$SvgCache.<clinit>(SVGLoader.java:81)
        ... 21 more
Exception in thread "JobScheduler FJ pool 1/3" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.intellij.util.SVGLoader$SvgCache
        at com.intellij.util.SVGLoader.loadFromClassResource(SVGLoader.java:142)
        at com.intellij.ui.RasterizedImageDataLoader.loadRasterized(RasterizedImageDataLoader.java:138)
        at com.intellij.ui.RasterizedImageDataLoader.loadImage(RasterizedImageDataLoader.java:55)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader$CachedImageIcon.loadImage(IconLoader.java:962)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader$ScaledIconCache.getOrScaleIcon(IconLoader.java:1031)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader$CachedImageIcon.getRealIcon(IconLoader.java:850)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader$CachedImageIcon.getIconWidth(IconLoader.java:778)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.AsyncProcessIcon.calcPreferredSize(AsyncProcessIcon.java:42)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.AnimatedIcon.<init>(AnimatedIcon.java:38)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.AsyncProcessIcon.<init>(AsyncProcessIcon.java:37)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.AsyncProcessIcon.<init>(AsyncProcessIcon.java:33)
        at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$initApplication$2$1$2.run(ApplicationLoader.kt:95)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
```

The following was the last line of that log and then it stopped printing anything on console:

```
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
```

how can I fix it??

Answer (score 3):

This error seems to indicate an instance of IntelliJ IDEA is already running. Perhaps in a degraded/invisible state. Try and kill all IntelliJ IDEA instances using the Task Manager or reboot your system. Then try running idea.bat again.

See also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-255562